# How do I use an item that's a child of a toolstrip item?

Tags: c#, toolstrip

Ok, so this is somewhat confusing, so bear with me.

I have a toolStrip item called "Downloads". When (and this is 100% random) a new item is added (it occurs when a website that I have no control over). I want to be able to read every item in the subset "Downloads" (so it's this.ToolStrip.Downloads.ITEM), one at a time, and use it. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do.  What type of object is Download?  Are you looking to just iterate over the items withing Downloads or are you looking to an item being added to Downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image it appears you are adding your download items to a ToolStripMenuItem. A ToolStripMenuItem has a **DropDown** property that in turn has an **Items** collection property. You can use the Items collection the same as any other to add, remove, etc. your downloads.

```
Downloads.DropDown.Items.Add("A File");
```

Comment: @chipperyman573 I have edited my answer based on your picture.

Comment: This lets me add an option to my DropDown, but not actually read the text of that DropDown.

Comment: Found out how to do it (using this answer) so I'm accepting it. Thanks!